# Filtering latest date among list of date based on year wise

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

have to filter dates in an array of dates, where it should consist of the latest date of the year.

```
data = [
  "2017-06-14",
  "2017-06-30",
  "2017-09-29",
  "2017-12-29",
  "2018-03-29",
  "2018-06-29",
  "2018-09-28",
  "2018-12-31",
  "2019-03-29",
  "2019-06-28"
]
```

expected

```
data = ["2017-12-29","2018-12-31","2019-06-28"]
```

Comment: add the code snippets what you tried so far

Comment: I do know how to filter these dates.

Comment: Please make an attempt before posting here. Since the dates are sorted, a simple `for` loop and comparing the first 4 characters against the previous item's 4 character and adding to an output array based on conditions perhaps? Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score 0):

Please always post your attempt and not just expected output so that we can assist in taking your approach forward as there can be multiple ways to solve same problem.

I have attempted it as follows:

1) sort dates in increasing order.

2) filter only year's last date.

```js
var res = ["2017-06-14","2017-06-30","2017-09-29","2017-12-29","2018-03-29","2018-06-29","2018-09-28","2018-12-31","2019-03-29","2019-06-28"]
      .sort((a, b) => a.replace(/-/g, '') - b.replace(/-/g, ''))
      .filter((d, i, c) => !c[i + 1] || d.split('-')[0] != c[i + 1].split('-')[0])
  
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a combination about grouping *by year* and filtering *by latest*.

This approach uses a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and the year as key and it checks if the date is greater than the actual date, then it replaces the old date.

```js
const getYear = date => date.slice(0, 4);

var data = [ "2017-06-14", "2017-06-30", "2017-09-29", "2017-12-29", "2018-03-29", "2018-06-29", "2018-09-28", "2018-12-31", "2019-03-29", "2019-06-28"],
    result = Array.from(data
       .reduce((m, d) => m.get(getYear(d)) > d ? m : m.set(getYear(d), d), new Map)
       .values()
    );

console.log(result);
```